# Extracting Page-level ASCII Text from a Collection of Multi-page PDFs?

Tags: sejda

I am trying to get page level **ASCII** text out of a series of multi-page PDFs. My current process is to split all of the PDFs with Sejda (an awesome tool) in batch and then extract text from the divided PDFs (in Sejda as batch) to corresponding text files. Is there an easy way to bypass the splitting phase and go straight to the page-level **TXT** files? I would like to just input a collection of multi-page PDFs and OUTPUT a corresponding TXT files for each page of each PDF. Any input or insight would be appreciated.

My process

```
File.pdf --> File-001.pdf; File-002.pdf; etc. --> File-001.txt; File-002.txt; etc
```

Comment: Since you mentioned Sejda, the feature you are talking about is planned but not yet implemented, maybe you want to keep on eye on it [here](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/issues/85)

Answer (score 1):

[Sejda version 1.0.0.M8](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/releases/tag/1.0.0.M8) has the task that you are looking for: [ExtractTextByPages](http://www.sejda.org/development/available-tasks/#extracttextbypages)

Example usage from the command line:

```
bin/sejda-console extracttextbypages -f /tmp/file.pdf -o /tmp -e "UTF-8" --pageNumbers 1 3 5
```